# Symfony2 MobileDetectBundle redirect is not working

Tags: php, symfony

I'm making a mobile version of my site using [MobileDetectBundle](https://github.com/suncat2000/MobileDetectBundle).

I'm trying to make a redirection to a mobile site like in the usage example. My config.yml is a copy/paste of what's in the readme.

```
mobile_detect:
    redirect:
        mobile: 
            is_enabled: true
            host: http://mobilesite.local
            status_code: 301
            action: redirect
        tablet: ~
    switch_device_view: ~
```

But when I hit http://website.local nothing happens. I'm using [User Agent Switcher Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) to appear as a mobile browser.

The bundle seems well configured because when I use `is_mobile()` twig helper it detects me as a mobile.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Guillaume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to erlangb I found the answer. Switching the user agent of the browser is not enough.

MobileDetectBundle creates a cookie named `device_view` so you have to remove this cookie to switch and appear as a mobile.

Comment: Thank you, I could have spent hours to figure out this

Comment: Thanks, that worked! For development you could also set the following key in your config.yml: `cookie_expire_datetime_modifier: "+1 seconds"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the guide correctly?

From README

"Now when you hit to http ://site.com you are redirected to http: //m.site.com. At this point if the http://m.site.com is configured to point to your project you will get circular reference error. To get rid of the circular reference error we want to disable mobile redirecting when we land on our mobile site."

You have to configure the mobile environment by following the steps 2 and 3 of MobileDetectBundle

Comment: The problem is, at step 1, I don't have any circular reference error. It seems there's no redirection at all.
To be sure I configured http://mobilesite.local on another virtualhost.
I also tryed to make step 2 and 3 but didn't work better.

Comment: Try to go here: https://github.com/suncat2000/MobileDetectBundle/blob/master/EventListener/RequestListener.php There is the listener that check if exist the mobile redirect. The function return false if is_enabled = true ...  protected function hasMobileRedirect()
    {

        if (!$this->redirectConf['mobile']['is_enabled']) {
            return false;
        }
Try set to false the "is_enabled" configuration or try to debug this event listener to check the behavior

Comment: I found the answer. Thanks a lot.